# How to combine Firestore (where, orderBy with start After cursor in flutter)

Tags: flutter

How to combine Firestore (where, orderBy with start After cursor in flutter)

```
getMoreData() async {
    if (moreDataAvailable == false) {
      print("no more data");
      return;
    }
    if (gettingMoreData == true) {
      return;
    }
    gettingMoreData = true;

    Firestore.instance
        .collection('clients')
        .where('alarm', isEqualTo: true)
        .orderBy('nameFs')
        .startAfter([_lastDocument.data['nameFs']])
        .limit(perPage)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((snapshot) {
          setState(() {
            if (snapshot.documents.length < perPage) {
              moreDataAvailable = false;
            }
            alarmData.addAll(snapshot.documents);
            _lastDocument = snapshot.documents[snapshot.documents.length - 1];
            isGet = true;
            gettingMoreData = false;
          });
          initialData.addAll(alarmData);
        });
  }
```

i'm trying pagination in my flutter app query works fine without orderBy 
but without i'm not getting pagination in my app also want where condition working i'm new at flutter please anyone can give me solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this package - [paginate_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/paginate_firestore).

You just need to pass `itemBuilder` and `query` like this and it implements pagination for you,

```dart
      PaginateFirestore(
        itemBuilder: (context, documentSnapshot) => ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.person)),
          title: Text(documentSnapshot.data['name']),
          subtitle: Text(documentSnapshot.documentID),
        ),
        // orderBy is compulsary to enable pagination
        query: Firestore.instance.collection('users').orderBy('name'),
      )
```